# InsertOnSubmit constraints

Tags: c#, .net, sql, database, linq

Is there a way that you check the constraints of a database when inserting a row with the `InsertOnSubmit()` function before using the `SubmitChanges()`?

Reason, I'm looping a Datatable generated from a csv-file. I'm inserting 1 row at a time to show progress. Now when a conflict occurs, linq rollbacks all the changes while I want the successful inserts stay inserted.

Now when running this code, it gives an error on the first conflict and there it stops. It doesn't insert any more rows and the rows before the conflict are overridden on the next time I run this code.

I hope anyone can help me with this. Below you can find a snippet from my code.

Regards, Thijs

```
foreach (DataRow row in Data.Rows)
{
  ProfilePrefillData profile = new ProfilePrefillData();

  //Paramaters
  profile.ProfileId = new Guid(row["profileid"].ToString());
  ...

  //Insert & submit
  db.ProfilePrefillDatas.InsertOnSubmit(profile);

  try
  {
    db.SubmitChanges(ConflictMode.ContinueOnConflict);
  }
  catch (Exception ex){}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about trying this:

```
List<ProfilePrefillData> badProfiles = new List<ProfilePrefillData>();
foreach (DataRow row in Data.Rows)
{ 
  ..

  try 
  {
    db.SubmitChanges(ConflictMode.ContinueOnConflict);
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
    // record which are the bad profiles
    badProfiles.Add(profile);

    // Remove the bad profile from items to be added
    db.ProfilePrefillDatas.Remove(profile);
  }
}

// Return some information to the user about the bad profiles so that
// they can be identified, corrected and reimported.
LogBadProfileData(badProfiles);
```

So when a profile causes an error, you remove it from the DataContext's collection (so that it wont attempt to reinsert them the next iteration) and store them in the `badProfiles` collection. You can then continue to iterate through the remaining profiles, and after they are done importing, log or report on the bad profiles so that you can correct them and attempt to reimport.